# Browser-sync used error

Tags: node.js, npm

As shown in the image below, I have installed **browser-sync** correctly and tried using it. It starts listening for file changes, but gives feedback "Cannot Get/", which I don't understand.

[image: command line output]

Comment: browser had opend  Automatic and  showing "Cannot Get/ "

Comment: It just a test file to start browser-sync server, not any code yet.